# Detectar tecla Shift está pressionada

Tags: javascript

Preciso que o `javascript` detecta se a tecla <kbd>shift</kbd> esta sendo mantida pressionada, enquanto isso fica executando a função, quando o usuário soltar, para de executar a função.

Eu estou tentando usar esse código em `Jquery`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("body").keypress(function(event)
      {
         if(event.keyCode == 16)   // se a tecla apertada for 13 (enter)
          {
            /* funçao a ser executada */
             teste(); // abre uma janela
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focando mais na parte da execução da função, enquanto estiver pressionada:

#### Sem um *Interval*

```js
var count = 0;
var mainFunction = function(){
 console.log(++count);
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if(e.shiftKey) mainFunction();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Pressione shift
```

#### Com um *Interval*

```js
// mainFunction será sua função executada

var count = 0;
var mainFunction = function() {
  console.log(++count);
}


var execFunction; //interval com a função

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    clearInterval(execFunction);
    execFunction = setInterval(function() {
      mainFunction();
    }, 10);
  }
})
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clearInterval(execFunction);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>O contador irá ser executado enquanto a tecla shift estiver sendo pressionada.</h2>
```

Dependendo do quão rápido deseja que sua função seja executada, recomendo o uso do `setInterval`, pois se prestar atenção a chamada é mas rápida. Além de claro, você poder ajustar o *delay*.

O que deve ser prestado atenção é a utilização do evento `keydown`, ao invés de `keyup`, já que a repetição só poderá ocorrer nesse evento.

Comment: Ideia muito legal! Valeu.

Comment: adorei, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar algo como este código. No caso você terá que adaptar seu código para ser aplicado no *body*.

```js
function teste(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if (evt.shiftKey) {
      shiftKeyDown = "Pressionado";
      alert(shiftKeyDown);
    } else {
      shiftKeyDown = "Não Pressionado";
      alert(shiftKeyDown);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="teste()">Pressione Shift (Ou não)</button>
```

Acredito que te ajudará um pouco.

Comment: Eu acho que isso vai funcionar para mim, enquanto estiver pressionada a tecla a função funciona, caso contrario não.