# Detectar Tecla SHIFT pressionada e click do botão direto do mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá

Eu preciso criar um atalho onde ao pressionar a tecla SHIFT + Botão ESQUEDO do mouse, exibe um alerta. Qual a forma de fazer isso bem simples e utilizando Jquery ?

Obrigado

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui, pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161539/57573

Comment: Obrigado Junior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey) pra isso:

**Com jQuery**

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) { // tecla shift
        console.log("shift+click")
    } 
    if (event.ctrlKey) { // tecla Ctrl
        console.log("ctrl+click")
    } 
    if (event.metaKey) { // tecla Meta (CMD nos teclados Apple ou Windows nos outros)
        console.log("meta+click")
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Sem jQuery:**

```js
function logChar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if(e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('shift+click');
  }
  else if(e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('ctrl+click');
  }
  else if(e.metaKey) {
    console.log('meta+click');
  } else {
    console.log('click simples');
  }
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="logChar(event);">clique aqui</a>
```

Comment: Olá Ricardo, que legal, obrigado. Eu estou aprendendo javascript e me surgiu uma duvida, na função esta assim / function logChar(e) /, tem a letra ( e ) como parametro do evento, correto ? Eu posso passar outros parametros por esta função, sem interferir no funcionamento do parametro do evento ? Como eu faço ?

Comment: Como essa função foi definida ali mesmo você pode passar quantos parâmetros quiser, desde que seja o mesmo número na definição e na chamada. Se tiver mais dúvidas abra outra pergunta!